Looking for an exactly solvable, nonlinear class of 2x2 differential equations which includes all linear systems
Part of my research consists on trying to approximate solutions to differential equations through topological conjugation with other, simpler ODEs. Naturally, this method is only as powerful as the class of equations that we're conjugating with.
This has lead me to search for exactly (analytically) solvable classes of equations with nontrivial topologies. As it turns out, even in the 2x2 case, these seem to be very rare.
I'm looking for a class of equations that:

Is (genuinely) nonlinear
Includes every linear 2x2 system as a sub-class

By genuinely nonlinear, I mean that they should not be topologically conjugated to linear systems. In other words, they should not be the result of some (continuous and invertible) change of variables applied to a linear equation.
Also, I'd like these equations to be at least as representative as the entire class of linear equations. In particular, this means integrable Hamiltonian systems are out.
I would expect something like:
$$
\dot x = Ax + F(x),
$$
where $x \in \mathbb{R}^2,A \in \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$ and $F = O(|x|^2)$. Any ideas?
